# How to set the height of this google table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-visualization

I have a google table that I'm trying to expand the height of to fit the entire container that is holding it, but the height won't change. The width did successfully, but the height won't.

Anyone with experience in google charts able to tell me how to change this height?

[JS Application](http://byronshilly.hostzi.com)

The code doesn't work in jsFiddle. Just click the submit button to see the chart, you don't need to enter in data. The relevant code is shown below:

css:

```
#mytable{
    display: none;
    margin-top: 60px;
    width: 410px;
    height: 270px; 
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid;
}

#table_div{
    width:410px;
    height: 270px;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="mytable"><div id="table_div" ></div></div>
```

JS:

```
function drawTableChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'months passed');
    data.addColumn('number', 'money saved');
    data.addRows([
        [6, competitorCost(6) - ourCost(6)],
        [12, competitorCost(12) - ourCost(12)],
        [18, competitorCost(18) - ourCost(18)],
        [24, competitorCost(24) - ourCost(24)]
    ]);

    var options = {
        width: 410,
        height: 270
    }

    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
    table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: false});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to set it with the following CSS

```
#table_div table{
    width:410px;
    height: 270px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing this opiton?

```
var options = {
    width: 410,
    height: 350 // your desired height
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get to your jsFiddle, but I will try my best to answer.  I did try this on my own with a similar example.  You declared the variable `options`, but never hand it off to the `draw()` function.

You have some alternatives for filling the entire height of the entire container holding it (which I assume is `mytable`).  If you want height which includes padding, scrollbars, and borders, use `offsetHeight` like below.  If you want just padding, use `document.getElementById('mytable').clientHeight` as the height.  If you your outer container is the entire window, you can use `window.innerHeight` as the height.

I think this is what you want in your `drawTableChart` function:

```
var options = {
    showRowNumber: false,
    width: 410,
    height: document.getElementById('mytable').offsetHeight;
}

var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
table.draw(data, options);
```

If you are not successful after trying this, it is possible that something else in the CSS is overriding the height.  At that point, I would open up your browser's developer console (typically accessed by pressing the F12 key) or similar tool and inspect each of the elements on your page starting with the table and working outward until you find what is going on.  You can also manually temporarily change the height in the developer console and see the changes before changing any code.

As a final note, I also have success setting the width and height to percentages like `width: '100%'; height: '100%';` within the `options` object.  That will also depend on what else is going on your web page and its CSS, the developer console may help figure that out as well if you have a problem.